# MongoDB pagination C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, pagination, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

**I am  doing paging of notification list using the below code,**

As you can see the model has so many fields which I don't want. I just want listed id, name only to show the outer details which does not need the content or anything else. How can I ignore these fields and get the 2 fields only with minimal process from the backend ?

> Paging code,

```
public NotificationCandidateList GetNotificationsByPagination(Guid candidateID,Guid courseID,int page, int pageSize)
        {
            var con = new MongoClient(DBConnection.MongoDBConnectionString);
            var db = con.GetDatabase(database);
            var collection = db.GetCollection<NotificationCandidate>("NotificationCandidate");
            var countFacet = AggregateFacet.Create("countFacet",
                PipelineDefinition<NotificationCandidate, AggregateCountResult>.Create(new[]
                {
                PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Count<NotificationCandidate>()
                }));

            var dataFacet = AggregateFacet.Create("dataFacet",
                PipelineDefinition<NotificationCandidate, NotificationCandidate>.Create(new[]
                {
                PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Sort(Builders<NotificationCandidate>.Sort.Ascending(x => x.NotificationStatus).Descending(x=>x.CreatedDate)),
                PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Skip<NotificationCandidate>((page - 1) * pageSize),
                PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Limit<NotificationCandidate>(pageSize),
                }));
            var filter = Builders<NotificationCandidate>.Filter.Eq("candidateId", candidateID.ToString())
                      & (Builders<NotificationCandidate>.Filter.Gt("expiryDate", DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()));
            if (courseID != Guid.Empty)
                filter &= Builders<NotificationCandidate>.Filter.Eq("course", courseID.ToString());
            var filtercount=filter & (Builders<NotificationCandidate>.Filter.Eq("notificationStatus", 0));
            var pendingcount = collection.Find(filtercount).CountDocuments();
            var aggregation =  collection.Aggregate()
                .Match(filter)
                .Facet(countFacet, dataFacet)
                .ToListAsync();

            var count = aggregation.Result.First()
                .Facets.First(x => x.Name == "countFacet")
                .Output<AggregateCountResult>()
                ?.FirstOrDefault()
                ?.Count ?? 0;

            var data = aggregation.Result.First()
                .Facets.First(x => x.Name == "dataFacet")
                .Output<NotificationCandidate>());

            return new NotificationCandidateList
            {
                TotalRecords = (int)count,
                notifications = data.ToList(),
                PendingCount=pendingcount
            };
        }
```

> This is my model Structure,

```
public class NotificationCandidate
    {

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        [BsonElement("notificationCandidateId")]
        public Guid NotificationCandidateID { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        [BsonElement("notificationId")]
        public Guid NotificationID { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        [BsonElement("shortContent")]
        public string ShortContent { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        [BsonElement("candidateId")]
        public Guid CandidateID { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.DateTime)]
        [BsonElement("createdDate")]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        [BsonElement("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        [BsonElement("content")]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        [BsonElement("url")]
        public string url { get; set; }
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        [BsonElement("imageUrl")]
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.DateTime)]
        [BsonElement("expiryDate")]
        public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        [BsonElement("icon")]
        public string Icon { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int32)]
        [BsonElement("fcmStatus")]
        public bool FCMStatus { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int32)]
        [BsonElement("notificationStatus")]
        public bool NotificationStatus { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        [BsonElement("course")]
        public Guid ExamTypeID { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int32)]
        [BsonElement("type")]
        public int NotificationType { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int32)]
        [BsonElement("commonCategory")]
        public int Category { get; set; }
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        [BsonElement("courseName")]
        public string ExamTypeName { get; set; }


        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public BsonDocument ExtraElements { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: you might find [this](https://mongodb-entities.com/wiki/Queries-Paged-Search.html) interesting in order to reduce the noise of the driver code and also be able to project the results to a different type.